# Bootstrap CSS row alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, spacing

Take a look at this image below:

http://gyazo.com/37bf79015bb42aa688898fb82f3d8c98

They should look like this: http://gyazo.com/9dd85e73e331ef035cfad1d8aa8b8d49

I've been racking my brain for a few hours on this issue, if anyone could point me in the right direction, thanks!

Here is my code for this

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .imgC{
            display:inline-block;
            float:left;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        .textC{
          display:inline-block;
            float:left;
        }
        .settings {
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
        }
        .settings:hover {
            background: rgb(231, 231, 231);
        }
        .dashboard-panel-6 {
           width: 49.5%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="col-md-6 dashboard-panel-6 settings">
                    <div class="imgC"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="vertical-align:middle;"></i></div>
                    <div class="textC"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">Profile <br></span><span style="color: #979797;font-size:9pt;">Change your basic account, email settings</span></div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <div class="col-md-6 dashboard-panel-6 pull-right settings">
                    <div class="imgC"><i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-3x" style="vertical-align:middle;"></i></div>
                    <div class="textC"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">Notifications <br></span><span style="color: #979797;font-size:9pt;">Tell us how to notify you and what you want to know</span></div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <div class="col-md-6 dashboard-panel-6 settings" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <div class="imgC"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-3x" style="vertical-align:middle;"></i></div>
                    <div class="textC"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">Password <br></span><span style="color: #979797;font-size:9pt;">Change your password</span></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your responsive size is off at smaller screen sizes, or at least that's what I found using JSFiddle.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JPzkS/)** - stretch out the Result window (bottom right) and see how it adjusts.

use `xs` or `sm` instead of `md` when viewing your code on a smaller window size.

i.e.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 dashboard-panel-6 settings">
<div class="col-xs-6 dashboard-panel-6 pull-right settings">
<div class="col-xs-6 dashboard-panel-6 settings" style="margin-top: 15px;">
```

Your code is technically correct, but your col-sizing will only happen on `col-md` or when a medium sized display is being shown (or resized), if your window shrinks down to a `sm` or `xs` however, the formatting will fall apart as you only specify `md` and nothing smaller.

Responsive also scale's the smallest size and everything upwards, so a `md` will size for `md`+ (aka `md` and `lg` sizes), while a size of `xs` will scale `xs`+ (aka `xs`, `sm`, `md`, and `lg` sizes)

Does this help?

Comment: @user3681580 Of course! If it was truly helpful please feel free to upvote my answer and mark it as correct (click the check mark) so that others may benefit from it too. :)